# Does JPA @Version feature play well with DTOs?

Tags: rest, jpa, dto

## Background

From an [answer of *OmniPersistence: usage of VersionedEntity is producing OptimisticLockException*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73189758/4903755) I just learned that in JPA
an attribute annotated with `@Version` **must not** be modified by the application but only by the persistence provider. Therefore, [OmniPersistence](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnipersistence) library does not even provide a setter method in its class [org.omnifaces.persistence.model.VersionedEntity](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnipersistence/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/persistence/model/VersionedEntity.java).

Originally I had a simple entity which is exposed by a REST web-service. I used a lot of classes from the library *OmniPersistence*.

**Model**

```
@Entity
public class City extends VersionedEntity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String postalCode;
    private String name;

    ... (getter + setter)
}
```

**Service**

```
@Stateless
public class CityService extends BaseEntityService<Long, City> {
    public Long count() {
        return super.createLongQuery("select count(c) from City c").getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

**REST Endpoint**

```
@Path("city")
public class CityEndpoint {
    @Inject
    private CityService cityService;

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAll() {
        List<City> cities = cityService.list();
        return Response.ok(cities).build();
    }

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return Response.ok(cityService.getById(id)).build();
    }

    @POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(City city) {
        cityService.persist(city);
        return Response.created(URI.create(String.format("city/%s", Objects.toString(city.getId())))).build();
    }

    @POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("update")
    public Response update(City city) {
        System.out.println(city);
        City updated = cityService.update(city);
        return Response.ok(updated).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    public Response count() {
        return Response.ok(cityService.count()).build();
    }
}
```

## Problem

In the mentioned answer it is advised to create a *CityDto* class. But I still have a problem thinking this through.

So in my `CityEndpoint#get(Long i)`-method I would return a `CityDto` class which has
no version attribute, so that the client can not alter its value. Then the client is changing some data and eventually calls
`CityEndpoint#update(CityDto city)`.

In this update method I need to convert the *CityDto* object to my *City* domain object. My problem is that the converted *City* object has no value for the version attribute if I create it based on a CityDto-object. And I am not able to set it because that is what the  JPA specification document (and OmniPersistence technically) prohibits.

The only way to get an entity reference with populated version attribute is to load it via JPA. With that I would need to **merge** the CityDto data into the managed entity. But I can not do that because in the time between the client calls *get* and *update* the object might get altered by other user, so loading the entity in *update* and merging the data might override some other changes and would contradict the whole purpose of the version attribute.

After all I want my web-service to be stateless and would not save some client state in terms of saving the entity of the get-request to merge any following updates in this particular object.

How can I solve this dilemma? Am I missing something?

Comment: i understand problem here. If you really wanna have a error when user 2 changed something in between user 1 load and save, i guess the only way is to send the version in your DTO. Then you send it back on update and compare it to the current version. If they match you can do the changes. Otherwise throw an exception. I really depends how important it is for you that the user gets an exception. Because after a reload he can change it anyway.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Ok, what you describe is pretty much a self-implementation of the functionality that JPA's `@Version`-feature provides. If I do the checking and exception-throwing myself I do not need this feature, just a non-annotated `int version` attribute. Or did I get you wrong? After all this is no rocket science, but I could not use the build-in feature.

Comment: you will use the @version to be sure that noone can change it in the entity. But you need a DTO version to get it back from the client and than compare it to the entity with has only a getter and the rest is from jpa itself